# How to use Automapper IMemberValueResolver custom resolver in CreateMap?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to convert an object's member from a short? to a bool using AutoMapper CreateMap.. using a resolver interface.

I created an IMemberValueResolver interface, class to the interface with a resolve function, and then tried using CreateMap with opt.MapFrom and opt.ResolveUsing - nothing works..

Interface and class compiles without error but only the CreateMap is in error.

Tried following documentation:
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Looked for 2 days now and tried EVERYTHING I could find, nothing works.. :(

This is what I have now..

Interface (IMemberValueResolver.cs):

```cs
public interface IMemberValueResolver<in TSource, in TDestination, TSourceMember, TMember>
{
    TMember Resolve(TSource source, TDestination destination, TSourceMember sourceMember, TMember destinationMember, ResolutionContext context);
}
```

Mapper configuration (AutoMapperConfig.cs):

```cs
public class IsBootstrapResolver : IMemberValueResolver<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel, short?, bool>
{
    public bool Resolve(PageTemplateDataContract source, PageTemplateViewModel destination, short? sourceMember, bool destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return sourceMember == 1 ? true : false;
    }
}

//NONE OF THESE WORK!!!!!
public class DataContractToViewModelProfile : Profile
{
    public DataContractToViewModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsBootstrapEnable, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IsBootstrapResolver>().FromMember(x => x.IsBootstrapEnable));
        CreateMap<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsBootstrapEnable, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(IsBootstrapResolver));
        CreateMap<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsBootstrapEnable, opt => opt.MapFrom<IsBootstrapResolver, short?>(!?!?!?!));
        CreateMap<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsBootstrapEnable, opt => opt.MapFrom(new IsBootstrapResolver()));
        CreateMap<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsBootstrapEnable, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IsBootstrapResolver>().FromMember(x => x.IsBootstrapEnable));
        CreateMap<PageTemplateDataContract, PageTemplateViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsBootstrapEnable, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IsBootstrapResolver, bool>(src => src.IsBootstrapEnable));
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the object mapped with a short? gets converted to a bool using a custom resolver.

Thank you!

Comment: There are passing tests in the GitHub repo.

Comment: I'm using AfterMap() for now to get around it but would still like to know how custom resolver should work.